# react-native android bundle error keystore load: keystore password was incorrect

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, apk

When running `./gradlew bundleRelease` I get :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsignerfailed with exit code 1 :
  jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: keystore password was incorrect
```

I followed the official doc here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

I tried to put the password in :

- `android/gradle.properties` in plaintext as the doc suggests
- macOS Keychain for obvious security reason
- `android/app/build.gradle` in plaintext to exclude a variable issue

I was able to assert :

- the password passed to `android/app/build.gradle` was the right one by using `java.lang.System.console(password)` to print it
- the keystore password was the right one by using `keytool -list -keystore app/my_key.keystore`
- when using keychain, the password was also rightfully set and recovered with `security find-generic-password -a [username] -s [keychain_password_key_name] -w`

I'm out of option here since I don't usually use Java or Gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given nobody seems to have the answer and after having dug to the end of the web, I found this :

https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2018/12/12/fixing-appcenter-android-build-error-usr-bin-jarsigner-failed-with-return-code-1/

The error is misleading and the implementation is wrong (/troll as usual in java).

Trashing the entire `build` folder and trying again fixed the problem and got gradle's mind straight.